# What is `NavType` for in Android Jetpack Compose Navigation?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I am interested in writing a wrapper library for Jetpack Compose Navigation that handles custom navigation argument types. I have a working prototype that handles any kind of data type leveraging kotlinx `Serializable`.
There's just one thing that I don't understand - and I will likely need to understand this if I am to write a complete library:- what is the `NavType` for?

The following articles leverage android `Parcelable` to achieve similar:-
[gitconnected.com](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/compose-your-android-navigation-with-custom-arguments-20d4467b5dfd), [droidcon.com](https://www.droidcon.com/2022/04/12/jetpack-compose-navigation-with-custom-navtype/)

Both examples go to the trouble of extending `NavType`, which includes custom methods for serializing and deserializing the argument data, however, from experimentation these methods are never called.  In fact, I can comment out the `arguments` parameter of the `composable` entry completely and it still works.

The [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/navigation/NavArgument) states *"the NavType object denoting the type that can be help in this argument."* and then further links on supported types, however, none of this answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

The `NavType` is needed when you want to add parameters to your navigation. Meaning, whenever you add a navigation parameter to a navigation route your `NavHost` needs to know what type the parameter has in order to be able to parse it correctly.

So when you want to pass on the *username* entered in **screen A** to **screen B** and you use your `NavHost` to navigate between them, you need to let the `NavHost` know that the parameter *username* is of type `String`. If the `NavHost` knows that it can parse it correctly and **screen B** can show the username entered in **screen A**.

Generally, the primitive types and arrays of primitive types are supported like described in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavType).
For custom `NavTypes` you can check out my [medium article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/compose-your-android-navigation-with-custom-arguments-20d4467b5dfd) ;)

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me.I understand the theory. In practice though, the parse, get and put methods overridden in the custom NavType are _never_ called. You have to serialize the data yourself regardless when setting the parameter.
The NavHost does not really seem to need to know what your end type is because you're creating a string regardless (which is default).